# how to remove redundant field from left join

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I am having following query to fetch message and images from two different table.
Here One message can have multiple images

for that i have written following query which is working properly and showing following result

```
select msg.messageid, msg.message, msg.sentby, msg.adddate, 
p_i.image_id ,p_i.small_pic_path 
from user_messages as msg
LEFT JOIN post_images as p_i
on msg.messageid=p_i.messageid
where msg.messageid='zpx1btrpvpa1360154523078'
order by msg.adddate desc
```

Output is

```
 messageid  message  sentby  adddate  image_id  small_pic_path
   1         abc      aa      12/2/12   6          /sdf/sdf
   1         abc      aa      12/2/12   7          /asdf/df
   1         abc      aa      12/2/12   8          /cxd/sxc
   1         abc      aa      12/2/12   9          /zz/szz
```

Here **messageid  message  sentby  adddate**  is repeating and while displaying in jsp page 
showing total 4 different message.

But I want to show 4 imageid and small_pic_path(based on message id) with a relevent message detail

I want to display as

1)       Message
        sentBy
        all small_pic_path of messag id of this message

1)       Message
        sentBy
        all small_pic_path of messag id of this message

2)       Message
        sentBy
        all small_pic_path of messag id of this message

3)       Message
        sentBy
        all small_pic_path of messag id of this message

Comment: How do you want your results to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really understanding your requirements, you write:

> But I want to show 4 imageid and small_pic_path with a single message
>   detail

How do you want to show those records?

Assuming you mean on the same line, then look into using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT msg.messageid, msg.message, msg.sentby, msg.adddate, 
  group_concat(p_i.image_id separator ';') imageids,
  group_concat(p_i.small_pic_path separator ';') picpaths
FROM ...
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aba20/3) to demonstrate the results.

If you are wanting to show the results differently, chances are you should handle that via the UI.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior when using a `JOIN`, you get the cross-product.

If you want the rows collapsed, use `GROUP BY` with the appropriate columns. In your case it might be:

```
GROUP BY messageid, message, sentry, adddate
```

Comment: Exactly.  And usually the output of a database query is going to be formatted before being displayed to the user, so you can build whatever format you want by looping through the dataset.

Comment: Ironically that was caused by the typo correction feature of this browser. Thanks for the note.